# how to delay html cdata loading with on demand scraping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping, jplayer

I apologize if the question is not explained clearly, since it is little overwhelming to me. Anyway here's the problem:

My site uses jQuery jPlayer to play remote url, however the remote url is dynamic, i.e., on each page loading I need to scrape the remote site to obtain the media url, and this url is put in the CDATA section in my html:

```
//<![CDATA[
(function($){    

$(document).ready(function(){

var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
{
    mp3: "dynamic url generated from php webscraping",
}, {
        .....

});

    });})(jQuery);

//]]>
```

I use PHP DOMDocument to obtain the mp3 url on demand, i.e.,

```
        $mp3_doc = new DOMDocument();
        //$output is the page grabbed via curl;
        @$mp3_doc->loadHTML($output);             

        $xpath = new DOMXpath($mp3_doc);
        $elements = $xpath->query("//div[@id='wp']//a/@href");
        // code to extract the actual mp3 url
```

The problem is: obviously this chunk of code slows down my page loading, since each time I'll need to download a remote page and then extract the mp3 url before I can begin to render the page.

My question is: since the mp3 url is used only when document ready, what are my alternatives to make the page loading faster, for example, load everything except the CDATA section? Maybe there is a javascript scraping tool that I can use instead of my PHP way?

Thanks,

Comment: The general approach to this is called caching: scrape once, then store the results locally.

Comment: ultimately caching is the solution, but at this time it's not feasible, the target site has over 100k posts, and i don't have that much space to host all the media.

Comment: There isn't likely to be another way.